# Query for JSON mapped field in isolation using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a `Hibernate` entity with a field that maps to a `jsonb` column. I can store and retrieve it using a `Repository` easily if I operate on the entire object:

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {
...
  @Column(name = "children", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "JSONB")
  @Type(JsonType.class)
  List<Child> children;
...
```

I would like to add a `Repository` method to load that column in isolation. I have tried:

```java
  @Query("""
      SELECT p.children
      FROM Parent p
      WHERE p.id = :parentId
      """)
  List<Child> getChildren(@Param("parentId") long parentId);
```

That gives me the error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.Child]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
...
```

The converter must exist in my project because I can load the `Parent` class as a whole, and the `List<Child>` is there. How can I re-use that to allow me to load this column in isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following options here,

## Option 1

Use JPQL something like this

```
@Query("""
      SELECT new com.package.entity.ClassName(p.children)
      FROM Parent p
      WHERE p.id = :parentId
      """)
```

Make sure that the constructer you are using exists in the class,

## Option 2

Use a @NamedNativeQuery instead of normal @Query

For Example:
Entity Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "userEntityMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = StatsDTO.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "campId", type = Integer.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "userCount", type = Byte.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "modifiedAt", type = Instant.class)
                        }
                )
        }
)
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "UserEntity.getStatsDTO",
        query = "YOUR_QUERY",
        resultSetMapping = "userEntityMapping"
)
@Table(name = "user_campaign_objective")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1224483473794225719L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "campaign_id")
    private BigInteger campId;
}
```

Repository Class:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<StatsDTO> getStatsDTO(Long campId);
}
```

## Option 3

Use Projection Interface

```
public interface QueryResponse {
    String getColumn1();
    Byte getColumn2();
    Integer getColumn3();
}
```

Make sure the column names are exact in the getters

Comment: Option 3 worked well for me, and was the easiest to set up. I did find that I needed to name the columns explicitly in the jpql: `SELECT p.children AS children ...` rather than just `SELECT p.children` in order to get it to work.

Comment: @Kevin interesting, while i have personally used option 2 and 3, i never used the jpql myself, may be it requires exact names of columns. Anyways glad things worked out for you!